# Changing the callback function name causes ABI break in C?

Tags: c, callback, abi

I want to check this issue.

Here is a callback definition in a library for application (e.g. Platfrom version 1.0)

```
typedef void (*module_change_callback)(int state);
```

Later,
I want to change the name to be more clear. (e.g. Platform version 2.0)

```
typedef void (*module_changed_callback)(int state);
```

Does it cause some ABI break?

thanks in advance

I think it is not ABI break, since it is not change of type signature. just, change of type name.

Comment: What you show are simply type-aliases. They are compile-time only things, and are lost once the compiler is done generating the object file.

Answer (score 1):

ABI only matters in the generated assembler once the C compiler has translated the source. During this process, C identifiers are discarded, so if you just changed the name of a type etc, it will generate identical code still. Modern C doesn't really allow you to write function declarations and definitions that mismatch either - only old C90 can cause problems with that.

You generally only have to worry about ABI/calling convention mishaps when you do questionable stuff like function pointer type casting/punning, or when calling a function defined in assembler from C or vice versa.

(In the context of hosted systems and Windows in particular, you may also have to worry about calling convention when using portable libraries like DLL.)

Answer (score 1):

No, ABI is not broken.

Both `module_change_callback` and `module_changed_callback` are aliases for `void (*)(int)` type. Those aliases refer to exactly the same type and they can interchanged freely.

```
// no warning
module_change_callback x = (module_changed_callback) 0;
```